# Rspecs with ruby file

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a ruby file airplane.rb

with a ruby class like so -

```
class AirplaneSeat
 attr_accessor :seat_row, :seat_column, :type, :order, :assigned_passenger

  def initialize(seat_row, seat_column, type, order, assigned_passenger = 0)
    @seat_row = seat_row
    @seat_column = seat_column
    @type = type
    @order = order
    @assigned_passenger = assigned_passenger
  end

  def get_passenger_seating
    #some code   
  end
end # end of class

# outside the class
begin
  puts "Enter the seating matrix as 2D array"
  seat_matrix = JSON.parse gets.chomp

  puts "Enter the number of passengers"
  no_of_passengers = gets.chomp
  raise "Please enter a valid passenger count" if (no_of_passengers.empty? || no_of_passengers.to_i <=0)

  AirplaneSeat.get_passenger_seating(seat_matrix, no_of_passengers)
rescue Exception => e
  puts "Error encountered -> #{e.message}"
end
```

So the ruby class has a few methods and couple of lines of code to execute outside the class, which takes input from the user and then calls the class method.

How do I go about writing test cases for this? I have the rspecs gem and spec folder setup done. 
I don't really understand how to begin with the test cases.
Any pointers greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a simple example say we have our file for a `Foo` class, `foo.rb`:

```
class Foo
  def call
    'bar'
  end
end
```

We can create a spec, `foo_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'foo'

RSpec.describe Foo do
  describe '#call' do
    it 'works' do
      expect(described_class.new.call).to eq 'Bar'
    end
  end
end
```

And then from the command line we can run the spec:

```
$ rspec foo_spec.rb
```

Comment: Thanks Kris!  This covers the basic concepts.

I have 2 queries/ doubts -
a) How do I test for the code outside the class, but still in the same file? (Input from user)
b) How do I pass variables to the get_passenger_seating method in the test?

Comment: a) try and put as much inside another class as possible, so that outside the class is just things like `gets` and `puts` (i.e. the user interface), no logic. If you want to test the UI, i.e. fake user input, then I'd start a new question. b) Not sure what you mean...